# How to make this recursive function return the smallest integer from a given start position?

Tags: c++

This recursive function takes the start position as input and returns the smallest integer in the vector from `v[start]` to `v[v.size()-1]`. But the program simply crashes. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you all for any help!

```
int Select_Smallest(const vector<int>&v, int start) {
    int small;
    if (v.size() == 1) { // if the vector has only 1 element
        return start;
    }   

    if (v.size() > 1) {
        if (start == 0) {
            if (v[start] < v[start + 1]) {
                small = start;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Select_Smallest(v, start + 1)) {
        if (v[start] < v[start + 1]) {
            if (v[start - 1] > v[start]) { // checks if the number before is greater than start
                small = start;
            }
        } else {
            small = small;  // if start == the last element in the vector
        }
    }
    return small;   
}
```

Comment: You are going to need to pass another parameter that is the smallest integer found so far?

Comment: This is  C++ code and not C. They are different languages so I have updated the tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- when the vector size is 1, you return `start` which is not a value from the vector.
- you always recurse with index `start + 1` and access the vector at offset `start`, eventually causing undefined behavior by accessing beyond the boundary of the vector.

Here is a simpler approach:

- if `start` is greater or equal to the vector size, return some conventional value such as `INT_MAX`.
- otherwise call `Select_Smallest` with an argument of `start+1` and return the smallest of that and the value at index `start`.

Here is a simple attempt:

```cpp
int Select_Smallest(const vector<int>&v, int start) {
    if (start < 0)
        start = 0;
    if (start >= v.size())
        return INT_MAX;
    else
        return min(v[start], Select_Smallest(v, start + 1));
}
```

This function does not use tail recursion, so unless the compiler is very smart, it is likely to cause a **stack overflow** for large arrays.